# How to troubleshoot "Undefined symbols for architecture i386"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to run an Xcode project developed by someone else and I keep getting the following error. Googling it suggests that I'm missing some dependency but if so I don't know which one. Supposedly the project already has all "Link Binary With Libraries" configured. I've tried different versions of Xcode and target devices and I get the same error. How can I narrow the problem down further?

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "___gl_pqSortExtractMin", referenced from:
      ___gl_computeInterior in sweep.o
  "___gl_pqSortMinimum", referenced from:
      ___gl_computeInterior in sweep.o
  "___gl_pqSortNewPriorityQ", referenced from:
      _InitPriorityQ in sweep.o
  "___gl_pqSortInsert", referenced from:
      _InitPriorityQ in sweep.o
      _CheckForIntersect in sweep.o
  "___gl_pqSortInit", referenced from:
      _InitPriorityQ in sweep.o
  "___gl_pqSortDeletePriorityQ", referenced from:
      _InitPriorityQ in sweep.o
      _DonePriorityQ in sweep.o
      _CheckForIntersect in sweep.o
  "___gl_pqSortDelete", referenced from:
      _CheckForRightSplice in sweep.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means that even if the compiler has the header file, when it actually linked them, it didn't find the real implementation of this code. So maybe you didn't linked your static library (only included the header file), or this static library hasn't been compiled for i386 architecture. So you can't make it work on simulator. You should check with lipo -info libMylib.a on what kind of architecture it has been compiled (armv6 - armv7 - armv7s, or whatever else)

Ok here what i have found:
This is the sweep file you are using.

http://oss.sgi.com/cgi-bin/cvsweb.cgi/projects/ogl-sample/main/gfx/lib/glu/libtess/sweep.c?annotate=1.2

Inside

```
static int CheckForRightSplice( GLUtesselator *tess, ActiveRegion *regUp )
```

there is

```
pqDelete( tess->pq, eUp->Org->pqHandle ); /* __gl_pqSortDelete */
```

By the way into the include file in sweep there is:

```
#include "priorityq.h"
```

So it let you compile because you have the header definition of the function, but you don't have the binary implementation. So you get linker error.
I dunno if you need to instal openGl in your mac ( i though it was already included), by the way i'm sure you don't have the (opengl/glu/libtess) libtess library, this is where there is the "priority.h" definition.

Here is the glu lib if found:
http://svn.netlabs.org/repos/gl2/opengl/glu/libtess/

So you should ask your friend if he has compiled himself the framework or not. Maybe you forget to add some link into your Xcode project, or the binary is missing from your mac, or not compiled into the i386 (even if i doubt of this). By the way i'm really not an openGl expert, but if you ask anyone into an openGl forum, they surely can help you.

Comment: A stripped-down version of the compile command is this: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -filelist project.LinkFileList. project.LinkFileList contains a bunch of .o files in this directory: ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/.../Debug-iphonesimulator/.../Objects-normal/i386/. If I run "lipo -info" on these files, I get "Non-fat file: filename.o is architecture: i386" for all of them.

Comment: mmm... i think you are doing lipo on the wrong files.  You should find the specific static library you are trying to link: the static lib one where you get all the gl_pqSortExtractMin, gl_pqSortInit; not the weep.o. It must be a libxxx.a data file. By the way, try first to find where this static library is and check if Xcode has correctly linked it. You can check it into "BuildSetting->Search Paths->library search path", there should be a link path where your static library is / are.

Comment: The thing is I get this error even when I run clang without adding any static libraries. Also, if this error is due to a missing library, how can I know which one that is?

Comment: I also have a lot of .d files linking to dependencies in another directory.

Comment: Is there some way to make clang more verbose? Perhaps a dependency is failing to compile but it isn't currently telling me which one?

Comment: .d files are perfectly normally, they are done to check dependancy, done by makeFile. And yes this is maybe a missing library. I 've googled and it seems it part of libGLU library. Is your project has something to do with NURBS or openGL drawing? If it, you need to install it on your computer

Comment: I have OpenGLES.framework. It's already in "Linked Frameworks and Libraries". Do I need to install something else?

Comment: I've narrowed the problem down by compiling files one by one. The error occurs when compiling sweep.o

Comment: Actually it's a dependency in sweep.d that doesn't compile: sweep.c

Comment: Thanks for your help! Would you be interested in helping out more and getting paid for it? Email me at olof at olbion dot com.