# Files that won't compile in iPhone project

Tags: iphone, xcode

I'm taking over an iPhone project developed by somebody else and cannot talk to the previous programmers. I'm running the project in XCode and it doesn't compile. I've narrowed the problem down to three files: render.c, sweep.c and tess.c. If I remove these files from Compile Sources the project compiles successfully and runs.

Questions:

1. Could it be that some external compile script was being used previously instead of the one configured in XCode?
2. Could it be that these files won't compile for the iPhone Simulator, but would compile for a real device?
3. Do you know what these files (render.c, sweep.c and tess.c) are for?

Comment: If everything works without them, they may be unfinished development. You could read the source to find out what they do.

Comment: You should have the best idea for what these files are for, we only have their names but you have the source code (and probably some bits of documentation)

Comment: True for my third question, but what about 1 and 2? The project files (project.xcodeproj) are in the repository so I would think I could just check it out and run it. It's also not a version issue - previous versions also have these uncompilable files.

Comment: what are the exact errors of compilation?

Comment: Compilation error here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12927854/how-to-troubleshoot-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-i386

Comment: Have you tried to compile for a real device?

Comment: I have now - they do. So it's a simulator problem.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to 2) is that the files do compile for a real device. For some reason they do not compile for the simulator. Why is unclear but at least it works.